# Save me from gibberish terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote, telnet

While logged in to a remote ssh session, sometimes I do cat to the wrong file (a binary or a diretory) and the display converts to gibberish. The only way out is to close the terminal and open a new one, which frustrates me because usually there is a lot of state related to the current terminal already.

**Update: while I received great answers, a little problem persists. See this follow-up [question.](https://superuser.com/questions/13158/usr-bin-reset-disables-backspace)**

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: As it happens in the title thread, I suggest you to correct the word "gibberish". I can not edit your post to correct only one character, as you know.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`/usr/bin/reset` might also do the trick.

Comment: see this: http://superuser.com/questions/13158/usr-bin-reset-disables-backspace

Answer (score 5):

An old trick that works on almost any other Unix type system, too:

```
echo "^V^O"
```

That is: Type the word ***echo*** than a ***double quote character*** then press ***CTRL*** and type the kev ***v***  then press ***CTRL*** and type the key ***o*** (the letter not zero) then type another ***double quote character*** then press ***RETURN***.

Answer (score 4):

Try "Reset" or "Reset and clear" from the the "Terminal" menu in the screenshot.

Comment: Won’t work in a different terminal application or the console.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering `setterm -reset`

Answer (score 1):

use **reset**, manpage: http://www.penguin-soft.com/penguin/man/1/reset.html

**cat**ing a textfile works too if i remember correctly

Comment: cating a text file will almost certainly not work

Answer (score 1):

Usual commands for these situations:

- stty sane
- eval $(tset -s)  # or eval `tset -s`
- echo ^[c         # You will need to type ^v ESC to get ^[ in bash command line

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you start using a practice of

```
less filename
```

instead of

```
cat filename
```

You would not land into such state often (ever?).

Answer (score 0):

when running `screen` in your ssh session helps as well, as that one will disable the more uncommon font switching escape sequences (but will of course still work with normal programs). The main reasons for screen are different, usually (switching between programs, disconnecting and getting back to your original programs when reconnecting, etc.)

running `reset` (or one of the escape combos) works if you ever happen to run into a garbled screen (or a screen that refuses to echo input) again...

Comment: The problem with running screen is that you lose useful stuff from the terminal like mouse scrolling.

Comment: IBTD. Yes, mouse scrolling won't work, but you get working keyboard scrolling and keyboard copy&paste that does not have problems with "dialog borders". Other programs (like "less") kill mouse scrolling, too.

Comment: In gnome-terminal, `less` doesn't kill mouse scrolling - it just scrolls the text in `less`, not the scrollback.

Comment: Hmm, I just installed `gnome-terminal` (2.22.3 from Debian Lenny) and I cannot scroll `less` with the mouse; the scrollbar is just grayed out as with `screen`. Just as with every other terminal emulator available. as soon as `less` or `screen` is closed, the scrollbar gets active again.