# /usr/bin/reset disables backspace

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote, telnet

Following [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/9192/save-me-from-gibbrerish-terminal), running `/usr/bin/reset` destroys my backspace functionality.

What can I do? After pressing backspace I get `^?`

Comment: what terminal application are you using? gnome-terminal? can you try it on xterm or konsole or other terminal app and tell us if you get the same results?

Comment: Also post the value of $TERM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will make the terminal interpret the key as Backspace:

```
stty erase "^?"
```

(`^?` can be either the Backspace key, or the literal `^` `?`.)

Comment: works for me +1

Answer (score 4):

Probably you need to fix you `TERM` variable to more accurately reflect the terminal emulator you are actually using. See [`man reset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset).

What's happening here is `reset` is putting things into a very vanilla state to insure that you can do *some* interaction with the terminal. If your login scripts set up any key interpretation rules *not* covered by your `TERM` variable (like [the one suggested by grawity](https://superuser.com/questions/13158/usr-bin-reset-disables-backspace/13175#13175)), you will have to reapply these by hand.

Answer (score 2):

The everything-you-wanted-to-know-and-more answer:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/BackspaceDelete/index.html